# Are blue spruce, pines, and evergreens "stable" in strong winds?

Tags: trees

We live in a mobile home park with a closely spaced row of evergreens, pines, and a blue spruce about 85 feet away. Some people wonder if these types of trees are stable and deep-rooted in heavy winds.

Comment: Individual trees - yes, usually. After all, those species survive in the wild in pretty hostile environments. But a "closely spaced row" might be a problem, because the air can't blow "round" each tree like it would if it was an isolated specimen. If the trees are less than 85 feet tall, you don't have a problem in any case - and an 85 foot blue spruce would be a record-breaker for height.